# Restore Workflow History in sharepoint

Tags: workflow

Is there any way to restore the **workflow history list** which was removed.

How can I recover my **workflow history list**.

Please suggest something.

Comment: have you deleted the history list

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't mean that you deleted the list itself:

The history in the Workflow history list still exists. You can add indexed columns to the history list and build a web part to use list ID and item ID to filter it based on currently displayed item.

But for future use I'd recommend that you create another list and write history items in folders there.